# Html and css mobile compatible

Tags: html, css, mobile, fluid

I'm trying to make a website for my friend's company and I did but it only looks good on desktop computers. On the phones and tablets looks really bad. I was doing so much research but couldn't find how to use fluid layouts or any other way. On some phones, divs just position in weird places and on some other phones they just look very small or cover the whole screen. And I have a white space on the bottom of the page(on phones). Here is a link so you can take a look: http://agrofit.hr/ p.s. it is on Croatian but you don't need to read :-))). Please help as soon as you can. Thanks!!!!

Comment: You should look into responsive layouts and how to use media queries. Your ask is unfortunately too vast for a quick fix.

Comment: That is why im asking. I dont know how to use them

Comment: You could use media queries:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp or a framework like Bootstrap: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Comment: Thank you for the links i will try

Comment: Well there are tons of places on the internet from where you can read and learn. Let Google be your friend.

Comment: I wouldnt be asking if i could find it

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ , https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp . Tutorials from w3schools on bootstrap and media queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using percentage measurements instead of pixel measurement's.

For example:

```
.example {width: 100%}
```

rather than:

```
.example {width: 700px}
```

Also as mentioned above use some CSS Media Queries.

So for example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
img {width: 200px}
}
```

This says that whenever someone is viewing on a device with a screen smaller than 700px, the image will be 200px.

Hope this helps.

[Edit] To Test Your Site On Mobile -

1) Open the webpage you want to test in Chrome.

2) Right click and click 'Inspect'

3) Then a grey window should appear either at the bottom of your browser or the right hand side of your browser.

4) At the top left corner of the new grey window there will be a two buttons, click the one that says "toggle device toolbar"

[image: Toggle Device Toolbar Icon]

You can now select different devices and see how they appear in each.

Comment: Hi and tnx and one more question because u probably know it

Comment: how to test how it looks without publishing

Comment: Hi Ian, It depends what CMS you are using. WordPress has a 'Preview' function built in. Also try checking your hosting control panel as most have a 'Preview Site' function built in.

Comment: I am coding on brackets and notepad++ and there is no mobile preview option and publishing on filezilla

Comment: @IanPETEK Ah i'll update my original answer for how to perform mobile testing in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You should read on css media queries and responsive layouts. You could also check out responsive frame works like `bootstrap`

Comment: start over using a bootstrap template :(

Comment: you can download a nice responsive template for free and have it installed in less than 10 minutes. They have templates that look a lot like your site. I know its not what you want to hear but thats my 2 cents worth

Comment: i know what is bootstrap i have it on the page but for the template i have to start over....

Comment: If you used bootstrap for the page, you probably didn't use it right. The page should be responsive already.

Comment: i did use it but not to make a page responsive but to put some elements to the page

Comment: There's a lot to read on for your website responsiveness. Bootstrap is just one of them. You could try using `%` for your measurements for example so it occupies `100%` or `90%` of any % of screen size. Just a tip

Comment: Do u know how i can test how it looks on mobile without publishing

Comment: If you using the google chrome browser, you could use the developer tools. It has demo viewport for almost all phones. right click->inspect element->ctrl+shift+M (on key board). If you look at the toolbar up there is a drop down menu to select different devices to see you website in

Comment: thank you soo much u saved me from publishing constantly :-)   :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    font-size: calc((.05em + 2vmin) + (.05em + 2vmax));
    line-height: 115%;
}
```

That seems to work. 
I tested on Chrome with Inspect's device profiles.